# Why control's DataBind is called before control's Page_Load method?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have a set of controls nested into each other. The top-most control has 'DataBind()' method call in Page_Load which triggers DataBind() method call for the inner controls.

I thought PageLoad should be fully completed before triggering DataBind events for controls (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx). Is that correct?

The problem is that this inner control don't have all data loaded (they should be passed from preliminary controls) and as a result crashed with NullPointer exception...

**Questions related to that:**

1. Why control's DataBind is called before control's Page_Load method?
2. How to properly initialize control data so before DataBind() called for top-most parent, all bottom/nested controls will have all required data

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure. I would guess because the availability of the inner control becomes an issue during page load so it is getting rendered in a funky order. In any case you should probably have the datasource for the inner control bind on the outer control's on OnDataBound/Binding event.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Init is happening before the page load and render. It says that during the init, all of the controls are initialized, or rather, all of the code for rendering those controls has been run but the control hasn't been drawn yet. If that's the case, then that happens way before the load.

Try performing the DataBind of the inner control during the OnDataBound event of the outer control. Or if on is dependent of the other, load the dependent control in the OnDataBound event of the dependency.